# Can 持续 have these 2 meanings?

Tags: meaning

I found these 2 example sentences, with English translations, for 持续。They are very different in meaning. Are both ok?

1. 高温天气持续了几天。 The hot weather went on for some days. 持续 = continued
2. 这足以持续到周末。It is enough to go on the weekend. 'go when?' 'on the weekend'

In 2., 'go on' does not really belong together, nor is there any sense of 'continue to do sth'.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It seems you understand the first sentence pretty well.

Regarding the second sentence, I think you're confusing `持续` and `足以`. `足以` is the word that means "enough".

这足以持续到周末 = This is enough to **last** until the weekend.

The key here is that `持续` indicates a persistence, something that continues on.

Comment: Aha, from the English I understood: 'It will suffice if we go (somewhere, to see someone) on the weekend. I didn't look at the Chinese carefully enough. Thanks! Upvote!

Answer (score 1):

(I am a native Chinese speaker. And I have been speaking English for working purpose several years.)

In my opinion, 2 is a typical `Enginese` (English-styled Chinese). Allow me to invent this non-existing word.

I think the English version should look like this:

`这足以持续到周末`  -> `This can last until the weekend.`

I think it is *over translation* to put `enough` in the middle for `足以`. A single `can` is good enough.

(BTW, enjoy your journey learning Chinese... It's concise, elegant, and flexible... Sometimes too flexible...)

Comment: Yes, I agree, the translation given with the Chinese sentence is bad. I didn't pick up on the '到‘ in there, and proceeded from the English, which was my mistake. I do enjoy learning Chinese though! It is an amazing language!